# Coordinate settings for 4k frame in OpenTK-Opengl

Tags: opengl, opentk, drawimage

My incoming data is 3840.2160, how should I edit my draw image function for this resolution? If you have a sample for 1080p, you can share it too.

I made some changes on the values in the code below. Do not take those values into account.

```
public void DrawImage(int image)
        {
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.PushMatrix();
            GL.LoadIdentity();

            GL.Ortho(0, 3840, 0, 2160, -1, 1);

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.PushMatrix();
            GL.LoadIdentity();

            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

            //GL.Color4(1, 0, 0, 1);

            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);

            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);

            GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);

            GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
            GL.Vertex3(2160, 0, 0);

            GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(2160, 3840, 0);

            GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
            GL.Vertex3(0, 3840, 0);

            GL.End();

            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            GL.PopMatrix();

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
            GL.PopMatrix();

            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        }
```

Comment: This question is totally unclear. "My incoming data is 3840.2160, how should I edit my draw image function for this resolution?" Why should you edit it at all?

Comment: @derhass The sample code I found was like this. my incoming output is not full scale to the screen and the display is reversed.

Comment: "The sample code I found was like this. my incoming output is not full scale to the screen and the display is reversed" BUt how would that have anything to do with the drawing function posted there. Those issues would persist no matter what your texture resolution is.

Comment: @derhass Don't the variables in the draw function determine how the frame will fit on the screen?

Comment: @derhass I guess you know about opengl. Actually I have a bigger problem. After running the window, no frames that I send are displayed. Even if I run the frame after sending it, it only prints the first frame on the screen. I want to use it for real time video streaming. How can I run in real time?

Comment: Not in a useful way. Those numbers you put in the `glVertex` only relate to the transfomations you set up, and since you only set up an ortho projection and identity for modelview, you they only relate to the ortho params, and when you choose `glOtrho(0,w,0,h,...)` and draw an axis-aligned  rectangle `(0,0)-(w,h)` the actual values of `w` and `h` will not make any difference (apart form setting them to 0 or some numerically insane range). That code will draw a viewport-filling rectangle, those numers are red herrings, and your issues lie elsewhere.

Comment: @derhass is there any way to print the incoming bitmap directly to the screen without dealing with these?

Comment: OpenGL is a rendering API, not an image viewer. It can be used to implenet what you want, but you will have to goo the long route and actually learn that stuff. And learning a rendering API is a huge task.

Comment: @derhass my stream is 4k 30fps. c # winform picture box. it doesn't support my requests. Can't I view 4k 30fps real time video with opengl?

Comment: OpenGL does know nothing about videos. As I said, you can implement it as some rendering backend for an image or video viewer. But if you want to go that route, you will have to learn the basics of OpenGL first.

Comment: @derhass not as a video. Can't we think of printing the incoming bitmap frame back to back on the screen?

Comment: I already told you that yes, this _can_ be done. This changes nothing of what I said before.

Comment: @derhass sorry i didn't see So how can I show each new data on the screen. Is there a function to refresh the screen?